# Codeigniter 3 - when I click a link, it uses the full path

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a view file with the following link (actually, I have a lot but this is just one example):

```
 echo anchor('Faq_public', 'Faq', array('class' => $faq_class));
```

When I hover over the link, I see what I expect, namely (bottom left hand corner of the browser gives me this):

```
 www.example.com/Faq_public
```

But when I click it, it uses the full path, and some more, is displayed in the url box for some reason as follows

```
 https://www.example.com/var/www/example.com/public_html/example.com/File_public
```

I don't have any idea how to correct this.  Any advise on how to debug appreciated.

Comment: `base_url()` is correct ?

Comment: Yes, it is.  $config['base_url'] = 'https://example.com/';

Answer (score 1):

Replace

$config['base_url'] = 'example.com';

With

$config['base_url'] = 'https://example.com/';

And check if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

It was a totally mixed up .htaccess problem